# Declaring variables inside C switch/case

Tags: c++, c, variables, local, switch-statement

Well, this is not actually a question..

I have just occasionally found out that there's an interesting way to declare local variables inside a switch/case block. Instead of using braces inside every case block, you can write:

```
switch (action) {
  int res;
  int value;
case ACTION_OPEN:
  res = open(...);
  ...
  break;
case  ...
}
```

So, I just wonder what C/C++ compilers besides gcc support this construction? It looks like a common fall-through. Any comments on this construction are welcome!

Comment: +1, just to find out if this is legal C++ or an accident of the compiler. Could be useful if it's allowed.

Comment: An easier way is to stop using C compilers that are outdated by 11+ years.

Comment: Still, except for the occasional fallthrough, I still prefer the braces inside every case block for more local scoping.  It is a matter of taste.

Comment: I changed the tag to C, as the question specifies C and the construction is completely and totally irrelevant in C++.

Comment: @DeadMG why would it be "completely and totally irrelevant" in C++ more than in C? The tag was set by the original poster, so I doubt removing it is a good thing. C++ has additional rules covering this (`res` and `value` cannot be initialized and cannot be non-PODs).

Comment: @Johannes: You'd just declare them inside the case statement. The only advantage to this is old C compilers where you can't mix declarations and code. You're right about the non-initializing thing, though, that amazed me to see. How insane.

Comment: @DeadMG you can declare them inside the case statement in C too. In C89 you just need to wrap a block around them (which you need anyway if you want to avoid compiler warnings (or even errors in the C++ case) like "jumps over variable declaration ..."). In any case, the question is about c++ and c ("So, I just wonder what C/C++ compilers"...) and removing the C++ tag is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any standards-conforming C or C++ compiler will allow this . Even an old-fashioned (pre-ISO C99) C compiler will allow this, but only because the variable declarations are at the start of a block/compound statement (denoted by `{}`).

Note that what follows a `switch` is almost a normal statement, except for the possibility of case labels:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    switch (argc)
      default:
        puts("Hello, world!");

    return 0;
}
```

So in ANSI C89, it's the braces that do the magic here.

Answer (score 3):

The switch body is just a normal statement (in your case a compound statement, looking like `{ ... }`) which can contain any crap. Including case labels.

This switch philosophy is abused by [Duffs device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffs_device).

Many people don't realize that even something like `switch(0) ;` is a valid statement (instead of having a compound statement, it has a null statement as body), although quite useless.

Comment: This has nothing to do with variable declarations. Duff did not declare variables inside his `switch` statement, as the C compilers of his day would have required extra blocks (which would probably have been translated to push/pop instructions).

Comment: @larsmans Duff's device has nothing to do with variable declarations, but it has all to do with abusing the switch structure employed by C and C++. In particular, that case labels are nothing really "special" but just jump labels. Once this is known, it's not surprising at all that you can put declaration statements before case labels in a switch body.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly spoken, the case that you present with `int` is allowed in all three languages, but for different reasons.

C allows jumping across the definition of any local variable (arithmetic, `struct`, `union`, array...) in all cases (for C89) and in all cases but one (for C99). The exception for C99 are variable length arrays.

C++ allows this only for data types that don't have a constructor or destructor, often referred to as POD.

So if you have a type `T` instead of `int` in your example in C89 this is always valid, and in C99 and C++ it depends on the type `T` whether or not this is correct.

In any case, all of this easily leads to uninitialized variables, so better don't do it if you can avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that C99 allows to declare variable (almost) wherever you want inside blocks, so that behavior should be considered legal.. and I don't see any actual risk since it's just a declaration.